# Extract similar values from bottom to top in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a table as follows:

```
FDate<-data.table("Date"=seq(1:6),"Cycle"=c(90,100,130,150,170,200),"i.Task"=c(NA,NA,"D",NA,NA,"A"),"Task"=c("D","A","C","B",NA,NA))
   Date Cycle i.Task Task
1:    1    90   <NA>    D
2:    2   100   <NA>    A
3:    3   130      D    C
4:    4   150   <NA>    B
5:    5   170   <NA> <NA>
6:    6   200      A <NA>
```

How can I extract the `Task` and the biggest of the corresponding `cycle`? The output looks like this

```
  Cycle Task
1   130    C
2   130    D
3   150    B
4   200    A
```

Comment: Do you need `FDate[, last(na.omit(unlist(.SD))), Cycle, .SDcols = 3:4]`  Not clear about the logic `lastest corresponding cycle`

Comment: I want the biggest cycle of the correspoding Task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `melt` into 'long' format, then grouped by 'Task', get the `max` value of 'Cycle'

```
library(data.table)
melt(FDate, id.var = c("Date", "Cycle"), na.rm = TRUE, value.name = "Task")[, 
     .(Cycle = Cycle[which.max(Cycle)]), Task]
```

---

Or a similar option with `gather` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(FDate, key, Task, matches("Task"), na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(Task) %>%
    summarise(Cycle = max(Cycle)) %>%
    select(Cycle, Task) %>%
    arrange(Cycle)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Cycle Task 
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1   130 C    
#2   130 D    
#3   150 B    
#4   200 A
```